# Flask template error with url_for()

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to represent and pass multiple pieces of data for a scheduling app I'm trying to write.

I have a calendar view layed out and I want to be able to represent the person who is being scheduled, the time they are being scheduled for, and the day that they are being scheduled for.

All of this needs to be passed through to the app route so that various queries can be performed with the information. An example of what my current dataset in dictionary form is represented here:

```
{'classes': 'CPSC-110', 'dayofweek': 'Monday', 'studentId': 3L, 'hourof': '10:00AM'}
```

my template code looks like this:

```
<form class="sumbittingThing" method="post" action="/appoint4">
    {% for thing in results %}
    <tr>
        {% if thing['dayofweek'] == 'Monday' %}
        <td class='mon'><a href={{url_for(appoint4, dayofweek={{thing['dayofweek']}})}}>{{thing['hourof']}}</a>
        </td>
```

Im getting an error that says

> "TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'"

If anyone has any suggestions for more easily passing the data, or knows how to fix this issue, i'd greatly appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies with this piece of code:

```
{{url_for(appoint4, dayofweek={{thing['dayofweek']}})}}
```

You don't need the second set of curly braces, as your code is already being processed as python code.  Your code should instead be:

```
{{url_for(appoint4, dayofweek=thing['dayofweek'])}}
```